# Copy constructor C1(const C1&) doesn't execute, but without it code doest'nompile

Tags: c++

The code

```
class C1
{

public:

    C1(const C1 &c) = delete;
    //{
    //  cout << "3\n";
    //}

    C1()
    {
        cout << "1\n";
    }

    ~C1()
    {
        cout << "2\n";
    }
};


C1 f()
{
    return C1();
}
```

Doesn't compile: error C2280: 'C1::C1(const C1 &)': attempting to reference a deleted function.

But, with copy consructor

```
C1(const C1 &c) 
{
    cout << "3\n";
}
```

It compiles and works, but the constructor doesn't execute.

Why ?

Comment: The copy constructor is elided, so it is not executed.  But it is still required to be there, or the instances are considered non-copyable -- and, hence, are not allowed to be copied.

Comment: Or, used to be required before C++17.

Comment: Justin, yes, it is